# React/Javascript Sort complex function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, sorting, methods

I'm trying to handle a sort function that toggles between dsc and asc.
It also needs to handle a certain table column name which is referred to as "header".
The expected outcome is to sort either "days" or "station" and have it toggle separately between dsc and asc.

```
handleClick={(val: any, header: string) =>
  val((val: any) => {
    const result = [...val].sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      return sortOrder === 'asc'
        ? header === 'Station'
          ? b.station - a.station
          : b.days - a.days
        : header === 'Station'
          ? a.station - b.station
          : a.days - b.days;
    });
    setSortOrder(sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'dsc' : 'asc');
    return result;
  })
}
```

This is my current function station filters properly but "Days Since Last Event" doesn't seem to work.

This is the handleClick on the child function

```
onClick={() => props.handleClick(setFilteredData, header)}
```

This is the sample of the data

```
[
  {
    days: 23,
    station: "Braidwood",
  },
  {
    days: 18,
    station: "Byron",
  },
  {
    days: 28,
    station: "Byron",
  },
  {
    days: 32,
    station: "Calvert Cliffs",
  },
  {
    days: 20,
    station: "Dresden",
  },
  {
    days: 320,
    station: "Dresden",
  },
];
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you _want_ to have happen?  I'm guessing that you want it to sort by one property _or_ the other, or _first one, then the other_...but it's not really clear.

Comment: the problem starts where you are changing sortOrder state, however, you should know that setState has some "timeOut" and it doesn't update immediatley. 
https://developpaper.com/on-the-data-delay-in-this-setstate/

Comment: @MattMorgan it to sort by one property or the other is correct

Comment: @yairmea Yes I think you're right I think in need to store which asc order for which property in the state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

As-written, your handler sorts a copy of the `filteredData` *and then* toggles the sorting order. This means the actual order is always inverted from the current `sortOrder` state.

If I had to guess, I would say the `onClick` handler is supposed to toggle the sorting order, *and then* you want the `filteredData` state to be resorted.

## Solution

The `onClick` handler should toggle the state, and the resorting can be done in an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `sortOrder` and `header` state.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredData(data => data.slice().sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    return sortOrder === 'asc'
      ? header === 'Station'
        ? b.station - a.station
        : b.days - a.days
      : header === 'Station'
        ? a.station - b.station
        : a.days - b.days;
  }));
}, [header, sortOrder]);

const toggleSortOrder = (header: string) => () => {
  setSortOrder(sortOrder === 'asc' ? 'dsc' : 'asc');
  setSortHeader(header);
};

...

handleClick={toggleSortOrder(header)}
```

Additionally, since the ascending/descending functionality is basically the same, I'd suggest converting the sort comparator into a higher order function that swaps the inputs and return a simpler comparator function.

```
const customSort = (sortOrder = 'asc', header = 'Station') => {
  const comparator = (a: any, b: any) => header === 'Station'
    ? b.station - a.station
    : b.days - a.days;
  return sortOrder === 'asc' ? comparator : (a, b) => comparator(b, a);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  setFilteredData(data => data.slice().sort(customSort(sortOrder, header)));
}, [header, sortOrder]);
```